# How to prove that certain points relating to a trapezoid are collinear?

Tags: geometry

Can you help me to prove that in any trapezoid, which is not a parallelogram, the following points are collinear?

- The midpoints of its bases.
- The point of intersection of diagonals.
- The point of intersection of the extended sides of trapezoid that are not parallel.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "intersection of the lines that support the sides of trapezoid" is not very clear to me.

Comment: Sorry it's just translated wrong, I meant that if we had to continue the sides of the trapezoid(that are not parallel) than they would meet in a point

Comment: Oh, I see now..

Answer (score 1):

These form a triangle:

- A: The point of intersection of the extended sides of trapezoid that are not parallel.
- B & C The endponts of the longest base.

And all the points are on the on the median from the point A.

So that is enough hint

GOOD LUCK

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality you may assume the corners to have the following coordinates:

$$(a, 0)\qquad (b, 0)\qquad (c, h)\qquad (d, h)$$

Then the points you mention have coordinates

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\left(\frac{a+b}2, 0\right) &\qquad&
\left(\frac{c+d}2, h\right) \\
\left(\frac{ad-bc}{a-b-c+d}, \frac{(a-b)h}{a-b-c+d}\right)
&\qquad&
\left(\frac{ac-bd}{a-b+c-d}, \frac{(a-b)h}{a-b+c-d}\right)
\end{array}
$$

All of them are incident to the line

$$2h\,x + (a+b-c-d)y=(a+b)h$$

I actually computed these coordinates and the corresponding line using projective geometry, where both operations (joining points and intersecting lines) can be expressed easily [using the cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/692464/35416).