# Simplify algebraic expression received from geometry

Tags: linear-algebra

$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(x_{A}-x_{B})b + (x_{C}-x_{A})c & (y_{A}-y_{B})b + (y_{C} - y_{A})c\\(x_{B}-x_{A})a+(x_{C}-x_{B})c &  (y_{C}-y_{B})a+(y_{C}-y_{B})c\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x_{A}((x_{A}-x_{B})b + (x_{C}-x_{A})c)+y_{A}((y_{A}-y_{B})b + (y_{C} - y_{A})c)\\x_{B}((x_{B}-x_{A})a+(x_{C}-x_{B})c) + y_{B}((y_{C}-y_{B})a+(y_{C}-y_{B})c)\end{bmatrix}
$

What we know about $x_{A}, y_{A}, x_{B}, y_{B},x_{C},y_{C}$ ?
They are coordinates of distinct and non colinear points 
What we know about $a,b,c$

$
a^2 = (x_{C}-x_{B})^2+(y_{C}-y_{B})^2\\
b^2 = (x_{C}-x_{A})^2+(y_{C}-y_{A})^2\\
c^2 = (x_{B}-x_{A})^2+(y_{B}-y_{A})^2
$

I tried to use Python with sympy package to simplify this expression but it doesnt work
I tried to use programs like Maple to simplify it but Maple only factored the denominator and failed to simplify it
I know that this expression can be simpified but I dont know how

Comment: Hint: the inverse of $2 \times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ is $\frac{1}{ad-bc}\pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}$

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler that you explain what is the initial problem, a triangle for which we want what exactly ?

Comment: Yes I know but after calculation inverse and then x and y i will get fractions which can be simplified but i dont know how Programs which i mentioned dont help

Comment: Pleas explain the objective. What do you want in this triangle ? The coordinates of a special point like the orthocenter ?

Comment: It will take me a while to write what i have got so far

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler approach.

With (your) notations $a=BC, b=CA, c=AB$ for the sidelengths of triangle $ABC$, its incenter $I$ can be expressed in the following way (known as "barycentric coordinates" representation ; you will find explanations for example in the second answer to this MathSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2090170/305862)):

$$I=k(aA+bB+cC)  \ \text{with} \ k:=\frac{1}{a+b+c}$$

which can be explicited with cartesian coordinates in this way:

$$\pmatrix{x_I\\y_I}=ka\pmatrix{x_A\\y_A}+kb\pmatrix{x_B\\y_B}+kc\pmatrix{x_C\\y_C}$$

Comment: Maybe but suppose we dont have introduced barycentric coordinates Angle bisector approach should also simplfy to this result but i dont see how

Comment: I like your "Maybe"...

Comment: It is because I know nothing about barycentric coordinates When I derived equations for angle bisectors I remembered only construction and I observed that after drawing first arc later construction looks like constructon of perpendicular line

Comment: Being a little experienced in different forms of geometry, I think that in particular for triangle geometry problems, you have to use the right tool(s) for each problem. Otherwise you loose a lot of time without benefit. Here, taking, right from the beginning, cartesian coordinates isn't the good approach. Barycentric coordinates is often a good tool, but you have also inversion, geometry with complex numbers, more or less mixed with trigonometry, etc.

Comment: I found correct equations for angle bisectors because if I substitute point you gave it satisfies this system of equations

Answer (score 0):

Initial problem was 
Calculate coordinates of center of inscribed circle in triangle with given coordinates of vertices

I found equations of angle bisectors (two of this equations I wrote here)

With help of programs like Maple i have got following results

$
x=\frac{((ay_{B}-ay_{A}+cy_{C}-cy_{B})((x_{A}^2-x_{A}x_{B}+y_{A}^2-y_{A}y_{B})b+(x_{A}x_{C}-x_{A}^2+y_{A}y_{C}-y_{A}^2)c)+(-by_{A}+by_{B}-cy_{C}+cy_{A})((x_{B}^2-x_{A}x_{B}+y_{B}^2-y_{A}y_{B})a+(x_{B}x_{C}-x_{B}^2+y_{B}y_{C}-y_{B}^2)c))}{(c(x_{C}y_{B}-x_{C}y_{A}-x_{A}y_{B}-y_{C}x_{B}+y_{C}x_{A}+y_{A}x_{B})(b-c+a))}\\
y = \frac{((-ax_{B}+ax_{A}-cx_{C}+cx_{B})((x_{A}^2-x_{A}x_{B}+y_{A}^2-y_{A}y_{B})b+(x_{A}x_{C}-x_{A}^2+y_{A}y_{C}-y_{A}^2)c)+(bx_{A}-bx_{B}+cx_{C}-cx_{A})((x_{B}^2-x_{A}x_{B}+y_{B}^2-y_{A}y_{B})a+(x_{B}x_{C}-x_{B}^2+y_{B}y_{C}-y_{B}^2)c))}{(c(x_{C}y_{B}-x_{C}y_{A}-x_{A}y_{B}-y_{C}x_{B}+y_{C}x_{A}+y_{A}x_{B})(b-c+a))}
$ 
But this can be simplified even more

When I draw equations of angle bisectors in Geogebra it looks lie they are written correctly but simplification of incenter coordinates is so complicated

Here is Python code for angle blsector approach

```
from sympy import *
xA,yA,xB,yB,xC,yC = symbols('xA yA xB yB xC yC')
a,b,c = symbols('a b c')
x,y = symbols('x y')
print('Lets find equation of bisector of angle A')
print('Equation of lines in which rays of angle are included')
eq1 = (yB-yA)*x-(xB-xA)*y-xB*(yB-yA)+yB*(yB-yA)
eq2 = (yC-yA)*x - (xC-xA)*y+yC*(xC-xA)-xC*(yC-yA)
print(eq1,'=0')
print(eq2,'=0')
print('Lets choose point B as point D')
print('Equation of circle with center at point A and radius AD')
eq1 = (x-xA)**2+(y-yA)**2-c**2
print(eq1,'=0')
eq2 = (yC-yA)*x - (xC-xA)*y+yC*(xC-xA)-xC*(yC-yA)
print('Solution of system of equations with circle and line')
print(solve((eq1,eq2),x,y))
pE = []
for p in solve((eq1,eq2),x,y):
    for q in p:
       q = q.subs(sqrt(xA**2 - 2*xA*xC + xC**2 + yA**2 - 2*yA*yC + yC**2),b)
       pE.append(simplify(q))
print('Possible points E')
print(pE)

# (y-yA)=-(xE-xD)/(yE-yD)(x-xA)
# (yE - yD)*(y-yA)=-(xE-xD)*(x-xA)
# (xE-xD)*(x-xA)+(yE - yD)*(y-yA)

print('Lets write equation of line perpendicular to DE and passing through point A')
print('and point E is the first point found by solving system of equations above')


bA1 = (pE[0]-xB)*x+(pE[1] - yB)*y - xA*(pE[0]-xB) - yA*(pE[1] - yB)

print('Equation of perpendicular line is :',bA1,'=0')

# (y-yA) = (yE-yD)/(xE-xD)(x-xA)
# (yE-yD)*(x-xA) = (xE-xD)*(y-yA)
# (yE-yD)*(x-xA)-(xE-xD)*(y-yA) 

print('Lets write equation of line parallel to DE and passing through point A')
print('and point E is the second point found by solving system of equations above')

bA2 = (pE[3]-yB)*x-(pE[2]-xB)*y -xA*(pE[3]-yB)+yA*(pE[2]-xB)
print('Equation of parallel line is :',bA2,'=0')

print('bisector of A :',simplify(bA1),'=0')
print('bisector of A :',simplify(bA2),'=0')

print('Lets find equation of bisector of angle B')
print('Equation of lines in which rays of angle are included')
eq1 = (yB-yA)*x-(xB-xA)*y-xB*(yB-yA)+yB*(xB-xA)
eq2 = (yC-yB)*x-(xC-xB)*y+yC*(xC-xB)-xC*(yC-yB)
print(eq1,'=0')
print(eq2,'=0')
print('Lets choose point B as point D')
print('Equation of circle with center at point B and radius BD')
eq1 = (x - xB)**2+(y-yB)**2-c**2
print(eq1,'=0')
eq2 = (yC-yB)*x-(xC-xB)*y+yC*(xC-xB)-xC*(yC-yB)

print('Solution of system of equations with circle and line')
print(solve((eq1,eq2),x,y))

pE = []
for p in solve((eq1,eq2),x,y):
    for q in p:
        q = q.subs(sqrt(xB**2 - 2*xB*xC + xC**2 + yB**2 - 2*yB*yC + yC**2),a)
        pE.append(simplify(q))
print('Possible points E')
print(pE)

print('Lets write equation of line perpendicular to DE and passing through point B')
print('and point E is the first point found by solving system of equations above')

bB1 = (pE[0] - xA)*x+(pE[1] - yA)*y-xB*(pE[0] - xA)-yB*(pE[1] - yA)
print('Equation of perpendicular line is :',bB1,'=0')
print('Lets write equation of line parallel to DE and passing through point B')
print('and point E is the second point found by solving system of equations above')
bB2 = (pE[3] - yA)*x-(pE[2] - xA)*y-xB*(pE[3] - yA)+yB*(pE[2] - xA)
print('Equation of parallel line is :',bB2,'=0')

print('bisector of B :',simplify(bB1),'=0')
print('bisector of B :',simplify(bB2),'=0')

print('Coordinates of center of inscribed circle version 1')
print(solve((bA1,bB1),x,y))
print('Coordinates of center of inscribed circle version 2')
print(solve((bA2,bB2),x,y))
```